# convert csv to Google spreadsheet in a html form

Tags: csv, forms, google-sheets

I have a small html form with some options. Based on the user's selection, currently the button click will result in the downloading of a csv file with the relevant information. What I ideally like to do is to be able to generate programatically a Google Spreadsheet from that csv file when the user requests it via the form.

I couldn't find this info. Will I need Spreadsheet's APIs for this or is there a simpler way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use the [Google Documents List Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingDocumentOrFileWithMetadataAndContent). Which will require that you make and authenticated POST call to this API with the appropriate parameters (described on the link). For Java and .NET Google developed some libraries that makes this job much easier, but you can call the API from any app/lang, just take a look at the "protocol" explanations on the documentation.

A think a simpler way would be to use [Google Apps Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/), a server-side javascript built into Google Spreadsheets and Sites. It's possible to write an interface to look like your html form. You'll have the advantage of it being highly integrated with Google spreadsheets. With 2 lines of code (literally) you can create a new spreadsheet with you csv values.

Comment: That API listing is massive, could you be more specific where the GET / POST API is?

Comment: First of all, I don't understand the down vote, I answered the OP's question clearly, just not yours! And if you click on the first link I posted and search for "upload" you should drop right in the desired part. Do you want that I write the program for you?

Comment: Ok, everybody just chill out. I added the previous comment from the iPad and I intended to vote you up. Must have missed and I downvoted you by mistake. 

Just edit your answer so I can be able to vote you up (vote is locked now)

Also, in the page you referenced there is indeed a GET/POST api for a lot of operations, but the Java API examples are shown by default.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it helped you after all.